# How to move points along their rotation in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to do something like this: randomly rotate points, place object instances, move points to new positions by a set amount BUT in the direction of current rotation, (and then repeat).

But I can't figure math needed to rotate the translation I want to perform.

Any idea how I can rotate translation (0.3m up along z-axis) using rotation information from points?

There is no Rotate Vector node in geometry nodes btw...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I can answer the question.

You need 3.0 to achieve this task. In Fields, there is a **Local space** setting in **Translate instances** node:

[image]

Old answer. New node **[Attribute Vector Rotate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_vector_rotate.html)** can generate direction from rotation:

[image]

Comment: Long awaited. I would rather work with Fields, but atm  'Point' menu items are being gradually introduced for operation with the new framework? So I'm hanging back for a while.

Comment: Well, it is too early to make solutions using fields, let's wait 3.0 release

Comment: @RobinBetts Small update for fields in answer

Comment: @Great stuff! I should update my old answers, too..

Comment: @RobinBetts btw, old nodes "Vector Rotate" and "Align Euler to Vector" has been returned!